# Undefined method 'attachment_path' for Rails engine model with ActiveStorage attachment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-engines, rails-activestorage, ruby-on-rails-6

I have a Rails Engine and Rails app, both running Rails 6.0.0.rc1.

Engine defines model with ActiveStorage attachments, eg.

```
module Shop
  class Product < ApplicationRecord
    ...

    has_one_attached :image
    has_many_attached :images
  end
end
```

Using this model in both engine's and application views and trying to call `= url_for(product.image)` raises an exception `undefined method 'attachment_path' for #<#<Class:XXX>:XXX>`. `product.image.attached?` returns true, thus attachment is available.

This code was extracted from Rails application where it worked just fine. Is there a special route helper for Rails Engine model attachments or any setup other than `rails active_storage:install` needed not mentioned in the documentation?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I got this working using `main_app.url_for(product.image)`!

Works both in engine views and main Rails app views.

Answer (score 1):

Just as reference for others, you can read more about this [in the Rails Guides](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html#routes).